# What is the meaning of $\delta(v)$ here?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.08288.pdf).

Could somebody please tell me what is the meaning of the $\delta(v)$ as it appears, e.g., on pages 4 and 6?

I cannot understand it’s meaning.

Thought for a while it’s the delta distribution. But how would that fit to (7), where the $\delta(v)$ seems to play the role of a “multiplication by $1$“ for $i> N_l$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose $\delta$ is just the delta distribution in $0$, as $M_i(v)$ looks like (for $d=1$) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\varepsilon_i}} \exp(-\frac{\vert v \vert^2}{2\varepsilon_i})$ with $\varepsilon_i\rightarrow 0$ as $i\rightarrow\infty$, which is a Dirac sequence, and we have $M_i(v) \rightarrow \delta(v)$ for $i=N_l+1,\cdots,N$. 
The definition of $\sigma_i$ just helps us to write equation (7) instead of equations (4) and (5), as we see as follows:
If $i\leq N_l$, the $\sigma_i = 1$ and we have
$$ \partial_t f_i + v\cdot\nabla_x f_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^N(k_{ij}\rho_j M_i - k_{ji}f_i),$$
which is exactly (4). If on the other hand $i > N_l$, then $\sigma_i = 0$ and hence
$$ \partial_t f_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^N (k_{ij}\rho_j M_i - k_{ji}f_i).$$
As $f_i(x,v,t) = \rho_i(x,t) M_i(v)$, this reduces to
$$ M_i\partial_t \rho_i = M_i\sum\limits_{j=1}^N (k_{ij}\rho_j  - k_{ji}\rho_i),$$
which is after canceling $M_i$ exactly (5).